# Puppeteer imported function error : this._pageBindings.get(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am importing a function from a different module, the name of the function is "startTheShow" and in order to expose the imported function and run this long function I am using this:

```
await page.exposeFunction("startTheShow",startTheShow);
await page.evaluate(async function() {
   await startTheShow('info','hi','banana');
})
```

The compiler will return this error:

```
TypeError: this._pageBindings.get(...) is not a function
```

[Here is the page.exposeFunction docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction)

Comment: It seems like `this._pageBindings` is not an object.

Comment: What can I do about it? is this a puppeteer bug? or something that I can fix

Answer (score 0):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const crypto = require('crypto');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
  await page.exposeFunction('md5', text =>
    crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('hex')
  );
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    // use window.md5 to compute hashes
    const myString = 'PUPPETEER';
    const myHash = await window.md5(myString);
    console.log(`md5 of ${myString} is ${myHash}`);
  });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

[Puppeteer Expose Function Source](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction)

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across the same issue - in my case the error was thrown because `startTheShow` was not defined.  I was not exporting it properly.